# How to combine two columns in new rows in SAS?

Tags: sas, datastep

I have a dataset as follows:

```
variable   level value
-----------------------
Age_group    1     0.1
Age_group    2     0.3
Age_group    3     0.2
Age_group    4     0.5
Sex          1     0.9
             0     0.6
```

I would like to reformat it to get,

```
variable          value
------------------------
Age_group   
   1               0.1
   2               0.3
   3               0.2
   4               0.5
Sex
   1               0.9
   0               0.6
```

Is there any way to perform this?

Comment: I don't understand this?

Comment: I edited the example.

Comment: Do you want Age_Group to be the variable name or "Age_Group" to be the first value of the 'variable' variable?

Comment: I want age_group to be the first value of the variable column. I edited the question for more clarification.

Comment: Why? Is this for reporting purposes or do you want a SAS data set like this?

Comment: This is for reporting purpose, but I want to modify my data before using my report macro.

Comment: It would probably be easier to adopt the "report macro" to understand how to put the extra line into the output.  Easy to do in PROC REPORT or data step report.

Answer (score 1):

The 'reformat' is more appropriately an output report versus a data set.

Example:

```
data have;
length variable $32;
input variable  $ level value;
datalines;
Age_group    1     0.1
Age_group    2     0.3
Age_group    3     0.2
Age_group    4     0.5
Sex          1     0.9
Sex          0     0.6
;

ods html file='report.html' style=plateau;
proc report data=have;
  define variable / order order=data noprint;
  define level / 'variable';
  compute before variable;
    line variable $32.;
  endcomp;

run;
ods html close;
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the output as a dataset and not a report (which you should perhaps consider), and you do not want to change the sorting of the input dataset, the following should work:

```
data have;
length variable $32;
input variable  $ level value;
datalines;
Age_group    1     0.1
Age_group    2     0.3
Age_group    3     0.2
Age_group    4     0.5
Sex          1     0.9
Sex          0     0.6
;

data newdata;
   set have(rename = value = old_val);

   if lag(variable) ne variable then output;

   variable = left(put(level,best.));
   value = old_val;
   output;

   keep variable value;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i don't have Sas installed and i didn't programmed for 3 years. But this could be helpful.
BTW it's not good to have your key field (variable) with spaces

```
libname class 'SAS-library';

proc sort data= (yourdataset);
by variable;
run;

data newdata ;

set yourdataset;
by variable;

retain variable;
if first.variable then newvariable=variable;
else newvariable=level;

run;
```

your will need to remove variable and rename the newvariable.

documentation
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214163.htm